# Update margin: auto when div resizes

Tags: css

is it possible to center a div inside a div so that when the parent div resizes, it still stays in the center? So far, I tried

margin:0 auto; and
margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;

Both work, however it does not reposition once a div size is changed. Thank you :))))

markup:

```
<div id='bottomcontent' style="float: left; position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0; background-color:#0b0b0b; height:100px; width:796px;">

  <div id="bottomleftbutton" style="margin-left: 25px;">stuff here </div>
  <div id="bottomcentertext" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">so far
  <h4>17</h4>
  places match your criteria</div>
  <div id="bottomrightbutton" style="float: right; margin-right: 25px;">stuff here </div>


</div>
```

Comment: [What's the problem?](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/5bM3Q/) Will need to some relevant markup.

Comment: hmmmm... it does work: http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/5bM3Q/3/

Comment: I edited my first post: the 'bottomcentertext' is what I can't get to reposition.

Comment: Can you put the markup in your question in to a fiddle with the relevant context? Since the above fiddle does indeed work, the error lies elsewhere, perhaps in existing css?

Comment: Thanks Marcel and Jonas! I have (actually whg has) solved the problem already. Thanks for all the help ! :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style the inner div with this:

```
position:absolute; 
top:0; 
bottom:0; 
left:0; 
right:0;
margin:auto;
```

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/2K4Gp/

Answer (score 2):

In order for your `margin:auto;` to work, you need to set a width on the `div`.

So if you did something like this

```
<div id="bottomcentertext" style="
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    width:300px; //NEW 
    color:white;">
```

it works.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/j96ft/